# conda environment via .yml file doesn't work

Tags: conda, anaconda3, virtual-environment

I'm dealing with conda environments and basically my problem is that when I try to get an environment from the following .yml file

```
name: voila-gpx-viewer
channels:
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- bqplot=0.12
- ipyleaflet=0.16
- ipywidgets=7.7
- jupyterlab=3.4
- nodejs=16
- gpxpy=1.5
- python=3.10
- srtm.py=0.3
- voila=0.3
```

just by typing this

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

on my linux terminal, than my system stocks almost forever in the situation reported in the following picture

[image]

and than, after a very long amount of time  I get this

[image]

Now I already have a conda-forge channel installed which should fix any problem. I admit I do not have a really fast internet connection, but still I can see a YouTube video without any issue, so I believe something goes wrong with my system and really I don't know what's the problem here. Could you help me, please?